# FATAL EXCEPTION: main while Android application running

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, fatal-error

I'm a total newbie and I'm studying at this time to make Android applications. Used one of tutorials. Things were well, but for some reasons my application began to crush every time I'm going to launch it.

I really tried very hard to see in LogCat reason but I didn't manage to. I would be very grateful if someone tell me what is going on.

**Here is LogCat:**

```
08-30 19:13:21.955: W/dalvikvm(7272): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41869d58)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272): Process: alesto.androidinterview, PID: 7272
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{alesto.androidinterview/alesto.androidinterview.SimpleQuestion}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2259)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5110)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at alesto.androidinterview.SimpleQuestion.onCreate(SimpleQuestion.java:56)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     ... 11 more
08-30 19:13:21.965: V/ActivityThread(7272): SCHEDULE 102 PAUSE_ACTIVITY_FINISHING: 0 / android.os.BinderProxy@429157e0
08-30 19:13:22.535: V/ActivityThread(7272): SCHEDULE 109 DESTROY_ACTIVITY: 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@428cbe18
08-30 19:13:22.535: V/ActivityThread(7272): SCHEDULE 140 TRIM_MEMORY: 20 / null
08-30 19:13:22.535: V/ActivityThread(7272): SCHEDULE 109 DESTROY_ACTIVITY: 1 / android.os.BinderProxy@429157e0
```

Here are **Front Page Activity** :

```
package alesto.androidinterview;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class FrontPage extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {

    Button bsimple, btough, bseeapps, brateapp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.front_page);

        //initializing buttons
        bsimple = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bsq);
        btough = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btq);
        bseeapps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bseeotherapps);
        brateapp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.brateapp);

        bsimple.setOnClickListener(this);
        btough.setOnClickListener(this);
        bseeapps.setOnClickListener(this);
        brateapp.setOnClickListener(this);

        //adding action bar
        LinearLayout frontLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.front_page_titlebar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.front_page_title_bar);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bsq:
                Intent i = new Intent(FrontPage.this, SimpleQuestion.class);
                startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.btq:
                Intent j = new Intent(FrontPage.this, ToughQuestion.class);
                startActivity(j);
            break;
        case R.id.bseeotherapps:

            break;
        case R.id.brateapp:
            Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("market://details?id="+getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri1);
            startActivity(goToMarket1);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

and its' **XML file**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/bgfirst"
    android:id="@+id/frontpagelayout" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bsq"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:text="@string/sq" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btq"
       android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/bsq"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:text="@string/tq" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bseeotherapps"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/btq"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:text="@string/soa" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/brateapp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@id/bseeotherapps"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_custom"
        android:textColor="#050000"
        android:text="@string/ra" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Destination Activity:**

```
package alesto.androidinterview;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SimpleQuestion extends ActionBarActivity implements
        OnClickListener {

    TextView tvQuestion, tvAnswer, tvTotalLength, tvPresentIndex;
    Button bleft, bright, bshow;

    String[] simpleQuestions, simpleAnswers;

    int index;

    public static final String defaultAnswer = "Press \"A\" for the answer";

    // variables and object of text-to-speech
    TextToSpeech ttsobject;
    int result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.questions);

        // initializiation of textviews and buttons
        tvQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvquestion);
        tvAnswer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvanswer);
        tvTotalLength = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvyy);
        tvPresentIndex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvxx);

        bleft = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bleft);
        bright = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bright);
        bshow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bshowanswer);

        Button bspeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bspeak);
        Button bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstop_mute);

        // setting onclick listeners to 3 buttons and SPEAK/MUTE buttons
        bleft.setOnClickListener(this);
        bright.setOnClickListener(this);
        bshow.setOnClickListener(this);
        bspeak.setOnClickListener(this);
        bstop.setOnClickListener(this);

        // importing string arrays
        simpleQuestions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.simple_ques);
        simpleAnswers = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.simple_ans);

        // setting values to different variables
        index = 0;
        tvQuestion.setText(simpleQuestions[index]);
        tvAnswer.setText(defaultAnswer);
        tvPresentIndex.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));
        tvTotalLength.setText("/" + String.valueOf(simpleQuestions.length));

        // adding action bar and customizing it
        LinearLayout questionLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.question_page_titlebar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
        getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.questions_title_bar);

        TextView category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_questions_titlebar);
        category.setText("Simple questions");

        // initialization of Text-to-Speech object
        ttsobject = new TextToSpeech(SimpleQuestion.this,
                new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInit(int status) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                            ttsobject.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Feature is not supported in your device",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bleft:
            bshow.setActivated(false);
            tvAnswer.setText(defaultAnswer);
            index--;
            if (index == -1) {
                index = simpleQuestions.length - 1;
            }
            tvQuestion.setText(simpleQuestions[index]);
            tvPresentIndex.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));
            break;
        case R.id.bright:
            bshow.setActivated(false);
            tvAnswer.setText(defaultAnswer);
            index++;
            if (index == simpleQuestions.length) {
                index = 0;
            }
            tvQuestion.setText(simpleQuestions[index]);
            tvPresentIndex.setText(String.valueOf(index + 1));
            break;
        case R.id.bshowanswer:
            tvAnswer.setText(simpleAnswers[index]);
            bshow.setActivated(true);
            break;
        case R.id.bspeak:
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Feature is not supported in your device",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (!tvAnswer.getText().toString().equals(defaultAnswer)) {
                    ttsobject.speak(simpleAnswers[index],
                            TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
                }
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bstop_mute:
            if (ttsobject != null) {
                ttsobject.stop();
            }
            break;

        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        if (ttsobject != null) {
            ttsobject.stop();
            ttsobject.shutdown();
        }

    }
}
```

Destination **XML file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_topbottom" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvxx"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_xx"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvyy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tv_yy"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:background="@drawable/main_background" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvquestion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="18dp"
            android:text="@string/tv_question"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvanswer"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="15dp"
                    android:text="@string/tv_answer"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="12"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_topbottom" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bleft"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/left_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bshowanswer"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"            
            android:background="@drawable/a_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bright"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/right_button" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tried **Clean** function in **Eclipse**. Didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Which is line 56 of `SimpleQuestion.java`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying error is specified in your logcat:

> 08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-30 19:13:21.955: E/AndroidRuntime(7272):     at alesto.androidinterview.SimpleQuestion.onCreate(SimpleQuestion.java:56)

and the line 56 is:

```
bspeak.setOnClickListener(this);
```

so `bspeak` is null. `bspeak` is initialized by

```
Button bspeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bspeak);
```

and that means that the view does not contain a view with id `R.id.bspeak`. You should either create the missing view `bspeak` or remove the code referencing it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is no xlm for this two button `bspeak` and `bstop_mute` that is y you are getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` android all ways refer via id .

```
  Button bspeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bspeak);
  Button bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstop_mute);
```

Please create a button for this id then you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! 
Actually `bspeak` was already defined in the separate XML file where title bar was described as independent layout. 
Other requests easily could find this view. I assumed that defining Button object inside of onCreate method was a bad idea.

```
Button bspeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bspeak);
Button bstop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstop_mute);
```

Eclipse didn't change color and didn't italize words `bspeak` and `bstop` unlike other buttons. Respectively `OnClickListener` didin't set in the strings below:

```
bspeak.setOnClickListener(this);
bstop.setOnClickListener(this);
```

But even that didn't work out. Real problem was about strings

```
LinearLayout questionLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.question_page_titlebar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);      
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.questions_title_bar);
```

were written after initializing buttons `bspeak` and `bstop`. Rising these strings above solved the problem.It's strange a little bit.